# Adding xml string to soap message

Tags: java, xml, soap

Using this xml file for creating soap message:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ord="http://xmlns.oracle.com/communications/ordermanagement">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ord:UpdateOrder>
         <ord:OrderId>26</ord:OrderId>
         <ord:View>BroadbandDSLOrderCreation</ord:View>

         <ord:UpdatedOrder>

         </ord:UpdatedOrder>

      </ord:UpdateOrder>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

XML String that need to insert in between UpdatedOrder tags.

```
<_root>
<DslOrder index="1422888817752">
<SubscriberInfo index="1422888817756">
<Address index="1422888817758">
<City index="1422888817761">OTT</City>
<PostalCode index="1422888817760">101</PostalCode>
<Street index="1422888817759">333</Street>
</Address>
<PhoneNumber index="1422888817762">438</PhoneNumber>
<Name index="1422888817757">xyz</Name>
</SubscriberInfo>
</DslOrder>
</_root>
```

Output of soap message must be like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ord="http://xmlns.oracle.com/communications/ordermanagement">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ord:UpdateOrder>
         <ord:OrderId>26</ord:OrderId>
         <ord:View>BroadbandDSLOrderCreation</ord:View>
         <ord:UpdatedOrder>
          <_root>
    <DslOrder index="1422888817752">
    <SubscriberInfo index="1422888817756">
    <Address index="1422888817758">
    <City index="1422888817761">OTT</City>
    <PostalCode index="1422888817760">101</PostalCode>
    <Street index="1422888817759">333</Street>
    </Address>
    <PhoneNumber index="1422888817762">438</PhoneNumber>
    <Name index="1422888817757">xyz</Name>
    </SubscriberInfo>
    </DslOrder>
        </_root>
         </ord:UpdatedOrder>
      </ord:UpdateOrder>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Need to add the XML String to soap envelope.

How can I add that XML string to soap envelope as shown in output?

I am converting xml file to soap message.Now i need to add xml string to soap message (in between same tags). Please help me

Answer (score -1):

You may want to look into using `<![CDATA[]]>` tags so that the message doesn't try to parse your payload (which happens to be XML).

For example:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ord="http://xmlns.oracle.com/communications/ordermanagement">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <ord:UpdateOrder>
        <ord:OrderId>26</ord:OrderId>
        <ord:View>BroadbandDSLOrderCreation</ord:View>
        <ord:UpdatedOrder>
            <![CDATA[
              <_root>
<DslOrder index="1422888817752">
<SubscriberInfo index="1422888817756">
<Address index="1422888817758">
<City index="1422888817761">OTT</City>
<PostalCode index="1422888817760">101</PostalCode>
<Street index="1422888817759">333</Street>
</Address>
<PhoneNumber index="1422888817762">438</PhoneNumber>
<Name index="1422888817757">xyz</Name>
</SubscriberInfo>
</DslOrder>
            </_root>
             ]]>
        </ord:UpdatedOrder>
    </ord:UpdateOrder>
</soapenv:Body>
```

If you are making the SOAP calls with a Java library, such as jax-ws, the library will take care of this for you (you only have to send the XML payload as is).